# Use a custom ssl_ciphers in node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, fetch-api

While trying to reach certain site via HTTPS, I get

```
write EPROTO 10284:error:14094410:
SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:
c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40
```

Basically - a handshake failure.

I guess it happens because to connect to this site one should use a custom `ssl_ciphers` (russian governmental GOST2012-GOST8912-GOST8912 , to be exact). How could I use such (or any other) custom chipher, preferably while using node.js [fetch library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) for connecting?

For note: I have only very basic understanding of SSL so feel free to demand clarifications.